# TypeScript interface with composite attribute names

Tags: typescript

I need to accept 2 sets of command line parameters to describe 2 distinct DB connections (to a PostgreSQL db, but this is not relevat for this topic).

Rather than introduceing a terrible code repetition I made the `interface` which describes the set of parameters describing a connection a generic type.

I'm almost done, but I'm stuck on the last step: writing a generic function to access the attributes of this `interface`.

```js
interface BasePosgresProgramOptions {
  postgresConnectionString?: string;
  postgresSrvServiceName?: string;
  postgresDb?: string;
  postgresDbFile?: string;
  postgresUser?: string;
  postgresUserFile?: string;
  postgresPassword?: string;
  postgresPasswordFile?: string;
  postgresHost?: string;
  postgresPoolMax?: number;
  postgresPort?: number;
  postgresSslCaFile?: string;
}

type ConnectionNames = "" | "Secondary";

export type PosgresProgramOptions<Suffix extends ConnectionNames> = {
  [k in keyof BasePosgresProgramOptions as `${k}${Suffix}`]: BasePosgresProgramOptions[k];
};
```

Till here everything works great! Now start the problem: I wrote the function as follows, but the return type is not so exciting... (**note:** check the later linked playgroud for details)

```js
export const getPostgresOption = <Suffix extends ConnectionNames>(
  args: PosgresProgramOptions<Suffix> | undefined,
  suffix: Suffix,
  option: keyof BasePosgresProgramOptions
) => args?.[`${option}${suffix}`];
```

So I tried to enfoce the return type changing the function as follows, but now it neither compiles. :(

```js
export const getPostgresOption = <Suffix extends ConnectionNames, Option extends keyof BasePosgresProgramOptions>(
  args: PosgresProgramOptions<Suffix> | undefined,
  suffix: Suffix,
  option: Option
) => args?.[`${option}${suffix}`];
```

What am I missing?

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QAoHsMDmUEG2UuRcAtgPIAOYwuIGyA3gFDLJ35hEkAwsxAQEjZgGUwUUAQD8ALmQYZcgNxcefARklQAbpOgHgSAHLUISlWpAFN3Xqt0ARAEY3Vs%204%200viDA8AMWAAG2tlbw0tZ35AgFUsKC87B1idROTQiNSfdKdMkmxMDAB3XCgAEzyYwoDi0orqnMjbfL843QAJPlrfDIbSXFwwgFk4AA8bEABXKndoTqLhqDAZ%20cWoZaHJDDDBOFb%209IBfDg4wAE86FGEQUXEmEEsqEmQAXmQAIm-kAB8fsYEMwqnAoFdvpoOBBJrw1shrrdkHhCIEyBQoNR6BIWAAeSSzGAwYCTZCwyAgKqse6PXGvEgAPk%207C0AG0ANbIUDIDkQK64GBoTA4fC6DGUWgMZ6sTDIAAGABI2BzTsrCcTSad5QBdZToLCo8XkSU4mWcnWaU7Q2HwsCIm4oUIYNZG9EmrFS3GsL5u4oe7HS5gYPG-RmaW2Ve1IlDA0F%200gBr0ylkJiWes3B0NxqngyHhi4AekLyAAKuEwsgABbQFAQAzQK5gKtybmsEmiIsl0s15DEMCzKAgB3IwWIlvt2YgJ7MNvIEC4e0YXDkyYIYCMewwuFR5Aglj2ggQMCo%20IkTPDr4EokkskUiBUmkiMT0qwYRkACi04IIGGUaaTC8Qw1W9mUBKcqggDsICqAAaLQMBvUllBA0l4O4XAgxAZQ%20QFIUDVFNF-UxQNvQ4ABKT5mR-DB5AAOjZJU2Ew3E1TYRDNUmbVLS7MsJ2QOAwEgKgGERFcHxgSokHHFB%200HYcY2QKpcBIEAAHJ7WaLlFC-SMEX3VRkCPE8VgvAAmFlr041dKWpZBaRfZ4GQwWDkAvGyHzs3CxwIgCSOTYNP2-KBf3-MV3X8oCrNAgFkAgqDQBg9CVCQyYUNS5KWOeZQLwoqiBJC2iGKYrLmDYjjb24zQgA) to easly check this problem.

P.S. I know I could enforse the return type specifying it, but I would prefer to apply a solution which infers the type from good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler isn't able to do much abstract reasoning about [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types. If you want it to understand that `getPostgresOption()` returns a type depending on the types of `suffix` and `option`, you'll need to express the operation in terms of something it can handle.  In what follows I'll use a technique described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

---

The main problem I see is that the compiler doesn't really see that you can index into `PosgresProgramOptions<K>` with a key of type `` `${K}${S}` `` where `S extends ConnectionNames`.  One way to convince it this is possible is to change it so that `PosgresProgramOptions` depends on `S` also.  If we write something equivalent to `` Pick<PosgresProgramOptions<K>, `${K}${S}`> `` (which is a supertype of PosgresProgramOptions), then the compiler will definitely be able to index into it with `` `${K}${S}` ``.

Like this:

```
type PosgresProgramOptions<
  S extends ConnectionNames,
  K extends keyof BasePosgresProgramOptions = keyof BasePosgresProgramOptions
> = { [P in K as `${P}${S}`]?: BasePosgresProgramOptions[P]; };
```

Now this implementation succeeds:

```
const getPostgresOption = <
  S extends ConnectionNames,
  K extends keyof BasePosgresProgramOptions
>(
  args: PosgresProgramOptions<S, K> | undefined,
  suffix: S,
  option: K
) => args?.[`${option}${suffix}`]; // okay
// return type
// PosgresProgramOptions<S, K>[`${K}${S}`] | undefined
```

And you can see that the return type depends on `S` and `K`.  Let's test it out:

```
const sppo: SecondPosgresProgramOptions = {
  postgresConnectionStringSecondary: "cxstr",
  postgresPortSecondary: 123
}

const str = getPostgresOption(sppo, "Secondary", "postgresConnectionString");
console.log(str?.toUpperCase()); // "CXSTR"
const num = getPostgresOption(sppo, "Secondary", "postgresPort");
console.log(num?.toFixed(2)) // "123.00"
```

Looks good.  `str` is inferred to be of type `string | undefined` (I assume eliminating `undefined` is out of scope for the question as asked; presumably one could start caring about *subtypes* of `SecondPosgresProgramOptions`.  Here we'll just use rely on [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to deal with `undefined`.) And `num` is inferred to be of type `number | undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-MIKFMmQ-zAXAEiY6ADiwBc3zc5A4O+QQAA1JAAFQAJS+HT6OQCYqAM2t610EyzNwCyrIhCy7OGKAwFc9yw087zfKygLcFCFZzwXVTIui+CvjU9TfwABn6r4gA)

Comment: When you asked the original question I commented to ask if this approach met your needs. You said it did, so I wrote up this answer. The point of my comment was explicitly to prevent a situation like this, where you come back later with an unmet use case that your example code didn't cover. If you've found an unmet use case now, you should post a new question. (more)

Comment: (continued) Modifying your existing question to expand its scope after it was answered isn't helpful for either of us. For me because it's not feasible to commit to indefinite scope changes, and for you because if I can't fix it then you'd be better off with a new question where others will see it and respond.  Please revert your edit to the question.

Comment: Thank you. I reverted the edit. I removed my wrong comment on this answer. I'll open a new question later.